# Is it possible to do one-line loops in Crystal?

Tags: loops, syntax, crystal-lang

I'm just learning Crystal and was reading a lot about the language. Coming from Ruby, I'm trying out some things that I was used to before, e.g., one-line loops:

```rb
x += 1 until x === 5
```

However, this is seemingly not supported by Crystal, is it?

```
In src/utils.cr:30:15

 30 | x += 1 until x === 5
             ^
Error: trailing `until` is not supported
```

Is it possible to do one-line loops in Crystal?

Answer (score 5):

Postfix `while` and `until` are not supported in Crystal.

You can however, often replace loops with `0.upto(5) { |x| ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Trailing loop conditions are indeed not allowed as the error message states, there is even a section in the [language FAQ on that](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/FAQ#why-trailing-whileuntil-is-not-supported-unlike-ruby).

To have condensed one-line loops in Crystal, one could use colons, i.e.,:

```
until x === 5; x += 1; end
```

I was also pointed to the [Crystal-for-Rubyists](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/Crystal-for-Rubyists) write-up.